# VBA - If two of three cells are true

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to construct and If statement that turns a tab Red if two of three cells are colored, or Turns green if only on is colored.  I was hoping that there would be an easier way to right it than three if statements like this.

```
Dim dateRng As String, num As Integer, j As Integer, irng As Range, frng As Range
dateRng = Sheets("Input Raw Data").Range("B" & counter + 2).Value
num = Sheets("Tool Setup").Range("C18").Value
NumPts = num * 3

For s = 1 To Sheets.Count
    With Sheets(s)
    For j = 1 To num
        If .Name = j Then
            .Range("A1:C1").Merge
            .Range("A1") = dateRng
            .Name = Sheets("Point Names").Range("B" & (3 * j - 1))
        End If
    Next j
    End With
Next s
For s = 1 to Sheets.Count
    With Sheets(s)
    For y = 1 To NumPts
        If .Name = Sheets("Reporting").Range("B" & (12 * y - 5)) Then
            For k = 6 To -1
                Set irng = Sheets("Reporting").Range("A" & (12 * y - k))
                Set irng = Sheets("Reporting").Range(irng, irng.End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight))
            irng.Copy (.Range("A2"))
            Next k
            .Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 12
            .Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
            If .Range("B7").Interior.ColorIndex > 0 Then
                a = 1
            End If

            If .Range("B8").Interior.ColorIndex > 0 Then
                a = a + 1
            End If

            If .Range("B9").Interior.ColorIndex > 0 Then
                a = a + 1
            End If

            If a >= 2 Then
                .Tab.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf a <= 1 Then
                .Tab.ColorIndex = 4
            End If
        End If
       y = y + 2
    Next y
    End With
Next s
```

Comment: You are testing to see if the color is `True`?

Comment: I am trying to get the tab to be colored red if the interior of the range is colored itself

Comment: I would make three binary variables that are 0 if the cell is not colored and 1 if the cell is colored.  Then you can test on If the summation of the variables is 1 or 2. This avoids having the create `if` statements that look through the possible combinations of coloring in the three cells.

Comment: You can test if `.Range("B7").Interior.color <> 16777215`, which `16777215` is the null color. Or, you could test for `.Range("B7").Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142`

Comment: The default value for `Cell.Interior.Color` is `16777215`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this may help you.  It still has multiple if statements.  But the statements are simple and don't have to deal with how the combinations of different cells being colored.

Also, I used `colorindex > 0` as the condition for having color filling.

```
a = 0

If .Range("B7").Interior.ColorIndex > 0 Then
    a = 1
End If

If .Range("B8").Interior.ColorIndex > 0 Then
    a = a + 1
End If

If .Range("B9").Interior.ColorIndex > 0 Then
    a = a + 1
End If


If a = 2 Then
    .Range("B10").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
ElseIf a = 1 Then
    .Range("B10").Interior.ColorIndex = 43
End If
```

Comment: You could narrow this down to one variable (just 'a') and just use `a = a + 1` for each `True`, a la `If .Range("B7").Interior.ColorIndex > 0 Then a = a + 1`. Then `If a = 2 Then`, etc.

Comment: @J.Fox That's a great point, I'll edit the answer.  Thank you!

Comment: @Jarom the code is turning all of my tabs green, when I know that some should be turning red

Comment: @ACohen. Did you debug, line-by-line to see where it fails?

Comment: @Jarom Yes, it runs through the first time fine and then it runs through the rest automatically

Comment: @ACohen - I am not Jarom :). Can you be more specific. I don't what exactly you are trying to say with that comment. Maybe also edit your post to include the code block that houses the lines as currently seen in question. I suspect you are looping which may be causing an issue. (Not loop itself, but how code is written in loop).

Comment: @ACohen I'd have to see more of your code to see what is causing the problem.  You can edit the post to include the loop like Scott suggested.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman  I edited my data. Hope its not too confusing/poorly put together

Comment: @ACohen I see what is likely the problem.  `a` needs to be reset for each loop.  The only time `a` is reset is when `.Range("B7").Interior.ColorIndex > 0` evaluates to true.  Try putting `a = 0` before the  `IF` statement for cell `B7`.  I edited my answer to include it.  See if that gets the expected results.

Comment: Came back when I remembered using an additive method would require a reset. My bad!

Comment: @J.Fox yeah, I didn't really think about it either.  I wasn't really in the loop mindset I guess....

Comment: @Jarom For some reason, it is still not working properly

Comment: @ACohen Hmmm....  Ok, at this point you should find a page that the code is not working properly on and F8 thru each line checking which `If` statements fire and the value of `a` at every point.  That might help you catch exactly what is going on.  From just looking at the code, I'm not sure what it would be.

Comment: @ACohen maybe the `.ColorIndex > 0` isn't working correctly.  Try what Rafael Matos said in his comment `.Range("B7").Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142`  I'm not familiar with that method, but it's definitely worth a shot.

Comment: @Jarom I set each range equal to their respective color, i.e. `RGB(255, 0, 0)`.  However, even if the statement is true, the code will think that it is false

Comment: @ACohen Ok, so you have isolated the problem to the condition of the `if` statement then correct?  That's progress.  Let me look a little more into that.  Are all of the cells that are highlighted colored `RGB(255,0,0)`?

Comment: `.Range("B7").Interior.color = RGB(255, 0, 0)`
`.Range("B8").Interior.color = RGB(255, 165, 0)`
`.Range("B9").Interior.color = RGB(255, 255, 0)`

Comment: I've tested all of this on my machine and it is working.  My last piece of advice is to do something like `.Range("B7").Select` before the `if` statement to make sure it is talking about the cell you think it is.  Outside of that, I don't know what the problem would be.